# How to compile gcc for ancient os?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I wanna compile gcc9+ for my host machine debian-buster with libc2.28 and gcc8.3.0 in packages. But target system will the same as my host machine so i wanna built binaries depend on my system libc version and libgcc version too. Static linkage with ligcc and libc may brake something so i dont wanna use this way.
I tried to configure gcc with this options:

```
$PWD/../gcc-10.3.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/GCC-10.3.0-sys --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --with-glibc-version=2.28 --with-stage1-ldflags='-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/' --with-boot-ldflags='-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'
```

But when i try to run binaries compiled by this gcc i get error like this:

> ... /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ...

What i do wrong? Thanx

Comment: Cheating: Link the new " libstdc++.so.6.0.26" to /usr/lib64/ as libstdc++.so.6 . ....... Not cheating : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[path to libstdc++.so.6.0.26]:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [app start command]`

Comment: i couldnt link against new stdlib because target machine has only old stdlib

Comment: I compiled gcc as you described here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j7qE9YKTT313B5VBg3kevzCNiykGkonO with ```export CC=gcc-8 CXX=g++-8 echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu``` and ```$PWD/../gcc-10.3.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/GCC-10.3.0-sys --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --with-glibc-version=2.28 --with-stage1-ldflags='-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/' --with-boot-ldflags='-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/' --disable-libstdcxx-pch
``` but i have the same error

Comment: I tried to compile with your gcc and i have the same error

Comment: I see your first comment. But how can i start with right libstdc++.so.6 on target machine? Target machine has libstd only from debian packages.

Comment: Install one of the example extra compilers https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing .... and do your experiments : See the first comment. .... And please specify "target OS".

Comment: Target os will be the same as host os but only with packages from repository.

Comment: Ok, i just used clang 11 from debian-buster-backports, it's much easier than backporting compiler by myself